# Session ID does not change on logout

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, authentication

I have searched almost everything on this but looks too confusing.I have a login control as below :

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" Width="300px" onauthenticate="LoginControl_Authenticate" onloggedout="LoginStatus1_LoggedOut">
```

It logs in the user and uses cookies for authentication.I also added extra code to make sure that entire session gets destroyed on logout button as below ;

```
void LoginStatus1_LoggedOut(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
}
```

The Session ID remains the same even after logout( for example, if i logout it does't direct me to the Login page as i want..so looks like it is not even executing the above event as i tried putting a breakpoint.When i log back in, it still carries the same Session ID.What am i doing wrong here
?
Another thing is that I am displaying the Session ID as :

```
 Session["SessionId"] = Session.SessionID;
```

and I am creating a new session like

```
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
```

Are these two different sessions or the same?

What are my options to clear all the session variables on logout.

**Note** : I also have this in Global.asax file but doesn't help

```
 void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
}
```

Comment: simply use `FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); Session.Abandon();` instead of  `HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();`

Comment: @SankarRaj OP is already in **LoggedOut** event. It means **FormsAuthentication.SignOut()** has been called already.

Comment: @SankarRaj - does this destroy the session forever, I mean the user should remain logged out even on clicking the back button.

Comment: @SankarRaj - I use FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); on Page_Load

Comment: @RelatedRhymes You do not need to explicitly call **FormsAuthentication.SignOut()**. If you reach to **LoginStatus1_LoggedOut** event, **FormsAuthentication.SignOut()** has been called already. FYI, **FormsAuthentication** is nothing to do with clearing Session State.

Comment: @Win - No.I am just using it on !IsPostBack so that the current user is logged out before logging in again

Comment: @RelatedRhymes You are on the right track. Please read my answer. Do not worry about SessionId and do not clear ASP.NET_SessionId cookie.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you do not want to manipulate ASP.Net Session cookie **ASP.NET_SessionId** directly.

Session State will be available whether you login or not, so you do not need to worry about **Session.SessionID**.

In other words, you only care about the value pair your added to the Session.

For example, myValue should be null in the following code after you clear Session state.

```
protected void LoginStatus1_LoggedOut(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Clear();
    Session.RemoveAll();
    Session.Abandon();
    var myValue = Session["MyValue"];
    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
}
```